# Restart Home programmatically

Tags: android, android-appwidget, homescreen

I'm developing on Android. I have to restart home and all its components (widgets, shortcuts, etc..). 
For example, when we have a Force Close, the home screen restart and reload all its components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to relaunch it ACTION_MAIN and CATEGORY_HOME intent. If you've just killed the app then this should restart it.

Comment: I want to restart my Home not my app. How I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

> I have to restart home and all its components (widgets, shortcuts, etc..).

No, you don't.

> For example, when we have a Force Close, the home screen restart and reload all its components.

If you have a "Force Close", you cannot execute code. Hence, what you want is impossible.

Comment: My problem is that some widgets doesn't refresh its state.
Only method to do this is restart home.

Comment: @Cecco: You are welcome to update your app widgets whenever you want via an `AppWidgetManager`. You do not need to attack the user by trying to kill the HOME screen.

Comment: @Cecco: Listen to CW. In your widget, you can set android:updatePeriodMillis to tell it how often to update. Note that with, I believe Android 1.6, the minimum update time is 1800 (or 30 minutes).

Comment: You don't even need to wait that long. You can update your app widget *anytime*. Just fill in the `RemoteViews` and pass it to an `AppWidgetManager` you get from `getInstance()`.